# PostgreSQL group by bug on Unicode strings?

Tags: unicode, group-by, greenplum

I have a very weird thing happening, where I noticed that a `group by (word)` wasn't always grouping by word if that word is a UTF-8 string.  In the same query, I get cases where it's been grouped correctly, and cases where it hasn't.  I wonder if anybody knows what's up with that?

```
select *,count(*) over (partition by md5(word)) as k
from (
  select word,count(*) as n
  from :tmpwl
  group by 1
) a order by 1,2 limit 12;
/* gives:
 word | n | k 
------+---+---
 いい | 1 | 1
 くず | 1 | 1
 ごみ | 1 | 1
 さま | 1 | 1
 さん | 1 | 1
 へま | 1 | 1
 まめ | 1 | 1
 よく | 1 | 1
 ろく | 1 | 1
 ネガ | 1 | 2   -- what the heck?
 ネガ | 1 | 2
 パス | 1 | 1
*/
```

Note that the following workaround works fine:

```
select word,n,count(*) over (partition by md5(word)) as k
from (
  select md5(word),max(word) as word,count(*) as n
  from :tmpwl
  group by 1
) a order by 1,2 limit 12;
/* gives:
 word | n | k 
------+---+---
 いい | 1 | 1
 くず | 1 | 1
 ごみ | 1 | 1
 さま | 1 | 1
 さん | 1 | 1
 へま | 1 | 1
 まめ | 1 | 1
 よく | 1 | 1
 ろく | 1 | 1
 ネガ | 2 | 1
 パス | 1 | 1
 プア | 1 | 1
*/
```

The version is PostgreSQL 8.2.14 (Greenplum Database 4.0.4.0 build 3 Single-Node Edition) on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc.exe (GCC) 4.1.1 compiled on Nov 30 2010 17:20:26.

The source table `:tmpwl`:

```
\d :tmpwl
Table "pg_temp_25149.pdtmp_foo706453357357532"
  Column  |  Type   | Modifiers 
----------+---------+-----------
 baseword | text    | 
 word     | text    | 
 value    | integer | 
 lexicon  | text    | 
 nalts    | bigint  | 
Distributed by: (word)
```

Comment: Does the same thing happen on newer PostgreSQL versions? There've been lots of unicode and utf-8 fixes since 8.4. Can you show some test data that reliably demonstrates the problem as a `CREATE TABLE` and a set of `INSERT` statement? Also, is this really PostgreSQL or it some vendor fork like EDB Postgres Plus or Greenplum? What does `select version()` say? (My intuition is that you're dealing with decomposed-vs-precomposed char or other utf-8 normalisation issues but I'd need to see the raw data to be sure).

Comment: It'd also be good to see the output of `convert_to(word, 'utf-8');`

Comment: As indicated earlier, the version is indeed Greenplum 4.0.4.0 (PostgreSQL 8.2.14).  BTW, it seems that when I change the distribution key of `:tmpw` (i.e. anything but `word`) then it works fine.

Comment: I'll try to replicate the problem in a simple case and see if it does the same on sqlfiddle, but I doubt it.  It really might be related to the distribution key.  I could also try the same thing in a newer version of Greenplum.

Comment: Ah, I missed the version embedded partway through the text and was thrown by the mis-tagging as `postgresql-8.4`. I suspect you're dealing with issues of failure to normalize utf-8 text before byte-oriented matching or failure to use locale- and charset-aware string functions in partitioning. I recommend that you produce a self-contained test case and submit it to greenplum as a bug. Please use the `greenplum` tag if you're using greenplum, there are a lot of ways it's very different to PostgreSQL.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that.  And my mistake for mis-tagging.  I am crunching on a deadline so will write the test cases later. Thanks again.